# How to create a table row with multiple columns in razor

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

Having trouble wrapping my head around how to approach this issue. Basically the way the data is coming from the DB there are multiple rows for an application but each row is unique, you may have an application with the same name but each row will have a different contact, or url. I want to display this data in a nicer format vs seeing each row straight from the DB

Example row https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1WRL.jpg

This is how i would like the data to appear, right now that application would have a row for every contact, and URL. I want the application to only be shown once. I am doing this in Razor NET CORE with C#

This is my current code that displays each row with repeating application names

Current Code https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxxkx.jpg

I am fairly new to Razor and NET CORE so this is a learning process

Comment: Do you have multiple app names or just one for all rows? perhaps you need nested for loops

Comment: There can be multiple app names, and they might all have more than one URL and Contact. Ive thought of doing nested for loops and then going through the table again and removing repeating app names,but i dont know how that will alter the table, and i want to stay away from doing something like this unless i cant find any other method

Comment: Well you could start grouping by the app name with linq, so you wouldnt have that problem. But im not sure on how to do that kind of nested rows, unless you use like a br instead of a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a couple of for-each loops i was able to get the data printed in the desired way. It seems like a bad way of doing this and I'm still looking for alternatives, but for now it'll do.

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var l in Model.names)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => l.appName)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => l.Location)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @foreach (var k in Model.contacts)
                    {
                        if(k.appName == l.appName)
                        {                    
                            @Html.Raw(k.contactName + " - " + k.contactRole + "<br>")  
                        }    
                    }
                </td>

                <td>
                    @foreach(var s in Model.filteredURls)
                    {
                        if(s.appName == l.appName)
                        {
                             @Html.Raw(s.urls + "<br>")
                        } 
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

One issue is that i have to create 3 separate lists from the data brought in from the DB(names, contacts, filteredUrls) in order to stop data from being repeated.

> result holds query data
>
> > names = result.GroupBy(x=>x.appName).Select(group => group.First());

this removes any duplicate information